# How to get a radio button index number from a each function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

When using the each() function in jquery for a group of, let's say, 3 radio buttons, how do I retrieve the 3rd button so when it's checked something happens?
Basically how do I choose the element I want to work with from the each() function?

Here is my coding:

HTML:

```
<form id="orderDefinition" name="orderDefinition">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" /><label for="">radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" /><label for="">radio 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" /><label for="">radio 3</label>    
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
var radioBtnCollection = $("#orderDefinition input:radio");

$(radioBtnCollection).each(function(){
    // From here, I don't know how to get the element
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's worth noting that *radioBtnCollection* is already a jQuery object, and doesn't need passing to jQuery again.  You can just use `radioBtnCollection.each(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the element using the [*this* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator):

```
radioBtnCollection.each(function(){
    alert(this.name);
});
```

Or by using the arguments supplied to the function:

```
radioBtnCollection.each(function(index, element){
    if (index == 2 && element.checked)
        alert("3rd element is checked!");
});
```

If you want to perform any jQuery methods on the element, you will need to wrap it with jQuery. For the first example, `$(this)`, for the second example `$(element)`.

You can just get the third radio button using [*:eq(2)*](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), instead of each:

```
if ($("#orderDefinition input:radio:eq(2)")[0].checked)
    alert("3rd element is checked!");
```

Comment: thanks man. it works!! Another question (sorry), how do I make sure that a radio button has to be checked in jquery?

Comment: @Shoaz: you can use the `:checked` selector, for example, `$('input:radio:checked')` would get the currently checked radio element.

Comment: No. Basically, I have this project where if you select the 3rd radio button, from the code above, it would highlight a group of checkboxes. But now the client also wants that when 1 of the checkboxes is checked, the the 3rd radio button is selected automatically as it they belong to the that radio button. I hope this was clear. I wanna know how to use jquery to achieve this. Sorry I'm kinda new to jquery...

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` wrapped as a jQuery object:

```
$(radioBtnCollection).each(function(){
    // this points to the element being iterated
    $(this)
});
```